# WinError 10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it - Django Python Error when Sending Email

Tags: python, django, email, email-validation

*I'm just learning Django and wasn't able to figure this out.*

**I'm trying to make my Django App send emails.
But keep encountering this error on Submitting**.
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYk98.png)

*This New Error Msg popped up out of nowhere
[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHkLD.png)*

I've turned the Allow less secure apps option ON in Gmail Settings, &
have tried adding

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

to the settings.py but it prints the emails in the console instead of actually sending them, which doesn't server the purpose

**Settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for expenseswebsite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
from django.forms import EmailField
import django_heroku
from django.contrib import messages
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-*akbxcj*md2z0&#vai@lw816t6p#te!fdo^#4j194^x7r7p-zo'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'expenses'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'expenseswebsite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'expenseswebsite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_USER_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'expenseswebsite/static')]
STATIC_ROOT =os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')



django_heroku.settings(locals()) #to create local heroku settings 

MESSAGE_TAGS = {

    messages.ERROR : 'danger' #to change the error in django to danger in bootstrap

}

#Emails



EMAIL_HOST: os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_HOST_USER: os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_USE_TLS: True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL: os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_PORT: 587
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD: os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')













# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

**Code in Views.py that deals with Email and Registration**

```
class RegistrationView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'authentication/register.html')

    def post(self, request):

        #TO REGISTER A USER
            #GET USER DATA
            #VALIDATE USER
            #CREATE USER ACCNT

       
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']   

        #TO KEEP THE VALUE EVEN AFTER MESSAGE


        context = {
            'fieldValues': request.POST
        }   

        if not User.objects.filter(username = username).exists():
            if not User.objects.filter(email = email).exists():
                if len(password) < 6:
                    messages.error(request, 'Password too Short')
                    return render(request, 'authentication/register.html', context)

                if len(password) > 36:
                    messages.error(request, 'Password too Long')
                    return render(request, 'authentication/register.html', context)

                user = User.objects.create_user(username = username, email = email)
                user.set_password(password)
                user.is_active = False
                user.save()
                email_subject = 'Activate your Account'
                email_body = 'Test Link Register Body'
                email = EmailMessage(
                    email_subject,
                    email_body,
                    'noreply@test.com',
                    [email],
                    
                )
                email.send(fail_silently=False)
                messages.success(request, 'Account Created Succesfully')
                return render(request, 'authentication/register.html')




        return render(request, 'authentication/register.html')
```

The .env looks like this

```
export DB_NAME =test                                                                                   
export DB_USER =test                                                                                  
export DB_USER_PASSWORD =test                                                                                                                                                                
export EMAIL_PASSWORD =test                                                                                   
export EMAIL_HOST_USER =test@gmail.com                                                                                   
export DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL =test@gmail.com                                                                                   
export EMAIL_HOST =smtp.gmail.com
```

OS - Windows 11